# Getting stacktrace of all threads without attaching GDB

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

Is there a way to print stacktrace of all threads without attaching GDB?

Or is there a command which I can use as gdb batch mode to print stacktrace of all threads?

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?  Were you able to get the stack traces?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a `thread apply all` command in GDB:

```
(gdb) thread apply all bt
Thread 12 (Thread 0x7f7fe2116700 (LWP 5466)):
#0  sem_wait () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sem_wait.S:86
#1  0x0000000000425358 in ?? ()
...
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f7feabc27c0 (LWP 5465)):
#0  0x00007f7fe76c5203 in select () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
```

Sadly, GDB seems not to be able to read the commands from a pipe, so to run the commands in its batch mode, a temporary file must be used:

```
$ gdbbt() {
  tmp=$(tempfile)
  echo thread apply all bt >"$tmp"
  gdb -batch -nx -q -x "$tmp" -p "$1"
  rm -f "$tmp"
}
$ gdbbt $(pidof $SHELL)
```

Then you'll only "temporarily" attach with `gdb` and then detach.

Comment: isn't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394935/getting-stacktrace-of-all-threads-without-attaching-gdb/43067836#43067836 better in that it avoids creating a `tmp` file?

Answer (score 19):

[elfutils](https://sourceware.org/elfutils/) among other utilities includes `eu-stack`:

> ```
> eu-stack
>     Print a stack for each thread in a process or core file.
> ```

It is faster than gdb or pstack, which is just a shell script wrapper around gdb. To print stack traces run `eu-stack` as follows:

```
$ eu-stack -p 2209
PID 2209 - process
TID 2209:
#0  0x00007f53476b667b __poll
#1  0x00007f5348f98e99 g_main_context_iterate.isra.23
#2  0x00007f5348f99232 g_main_loop_run
#3  0x000055e604b1e56a main
#4  0x00007f53475cc00a __libc_start_main
#5  0x000055e604b1e76a _start
TID 2223:
#0  0x00007f53476b667b __poll
#1  0x00007f5348f98e99 g_main_context_iterate.isra.23
#2  0x00007f5348f98fac g_main_context_iteration
#3  0x00007f5348f98ff1 glib_worker_main
#4  0x00007f5348fc0486 g_thread_proxy
#5  0x00007f534813761b start_thread
#6  0x00007f53476c2c2f __clone
TID 2224:
#0  0x00007f53476b667b __poll
#1  0x00007f5348f98e99 g_main_context_iterate.isra.23
#2  0x00007f5348f99232 g_main_loop_run
#3  0x00007f5349581b56 gdbus_shared_thread_func
#4  0x00007f5348fc0486 g_thread_proxy
#5  0x00007f534813761b start_thread
#6  0x00007f53476c2c2f __clone
```

Comment: On a modern 64 bit Linux, this should be marked as the correct answer!

Comment: I couldn't figure out a way to get this to show line numbers?

Comment: Try to run with `-s` option: `eu-stack -s -p <pid>`. It shows at least some line numbers where debug info is available.

Answer (score 5):

The following script works for me on linux
Please note that it first finds out the directory of the executable and changes to that directory (because executable can have shared libraries with relative path by using -Wl,-rpath,$dir specified during linking, and you would like gdb to find the symbols for these shared libraries for the stack trace).
It also assumes that gdb is present on the system.

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=$1

EXE=`readlink -f /proc/$pid/exe`

DIR=`dirname $EXE`

cd $DIR

gdb $EXE --batch -ex "attach $pid" -ex "thread apply all bt"
```

Answer (score 4):

pstack?

Usage:

```
pstack <pid>
```

From the man page:

```
pstack - print a stack trace of a running process
...
If the process is part of a thread group, then pstack will print out a stack trace for each of the threads in the group.
```

Comment: It really does not work (and is not as common as GDB): "pstack currently works only on Linux, only on an x86 machine running 32 bit  ELF  binaries (64 bit not supported)"

Comment: @fork0: "really does not work" -- can you please be more specific?  Also, OP tagged question as "Linux" so pstack is relevant.

Comment: @fork0: "64 bit not supported" -- source?  I've got a 64-bit machine (Linux 2.6.18) and pstack is there.

Comment: The man page of pstack on Debian Testing. It does not show anything useful on my 64bit/3.5.3 machine (ip of some random thread and nothing else)

Comment: I'm on CentOS 5.3 (both 32- and 64-bit) and pstack here works perfectly.  Thanks for the info re: Debian, though.

Comment: On Fedora pstack is a convenient shell script wrapper that does `thread apply all` in gdb. So this answer is basically the same as fork0's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this:

```
pidof program | xargs -n1 sudo gdb --batch -ex "thread apply all bt" -p
```

Answer (score 0):

As in linux All threads are essentially Light weight processes , they get individual LWP PIDs. you can dump the status of these by using a `ps` or `top` based script or  `echo`ing the `w` in `/proc/sysrq-trigger`. This will give you the `I/O` state of the threads in the `/var/log/messages`.

This won't give you the complete stack trace though . but its a good way to debug the thread states on periodical intervals.

you can also explore whats current scheduler state by looking into `/proc/sched_debug` to see which tasks are getting scheduled and so on .