# Print stack trace of all threads without attaching GDB

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, embedded-linux, stack-trace

Is it possible to programatically print out stack trace of all running threads without attaching GDB? The application is running on an embedded system with Linux.

I've found a [very similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394935/getting-stacktrace-of-all-threads-without-attaching-gdb) but the solution uses a special GDB command.

Comment: The question is what you even *mean* by that. Unless the program is stopped, there isn't such a thing as "all threads". Threads may be spawned and destroyed all the time. You can do what gdb does manually by sending SIGSTOP and attaching ptrace.

Comment: Is each thread going to call the stack trace function? If so, this might help: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html.

Comment: It's possible, but you'd be re-implementing a moderate chunk of gdb or at least gdbserver - so why not use the existing version?

Comment: `cat /proc/<pid>/task/*/stack`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been solved with the help of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402160/getting-a-backtrace-of-other-thread) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765158/printing-a-stack-trace-from-another-thread?lq=1).

Quoting:

> Signal Handling with the help of backtrace can solve your purpose.
>
> I mean if you have a PID of the Thread, you can raise a signal for
>   that thread. and in the handler you can use the backtrace. since the
>   handler would be executing in that partucular thread, the backtrace
>   there would be the output what you are needed.