# How to obtain thread stack information WITHOUT pstack and gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, stack, stack-trace

Is there a way of obtaining information about why program got stuck, when not being able to insert any logs and not having pstack and gdb, on some very tiny linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting stacktrace of all threads without attaching GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394935/getting-stacktrace-of-all-threads-without-attaching-gdb)

Comment: Not a duplicate, because I ask specifically about situation when I don't have gdb or pstack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to do the following:

1. Be able to retrieve manipulate and print a stack trace *within your own program*
2. Install a signal handler (say, for SIGUSR1) for your process which would do that
3. Send the signal to your program when it's stuck - control will be moved to the signal handler (assuming you haven't masked out signals).

Now (2.) and (3.) and pretty simple. For (3.) it's `kill -USR1 1234` (for a process with ID 1234). For (2.), it's:

```
#include <signal.h>
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
sighandler_t sigset(int sig, sighandler_t disp);
```

(read `man sigset` for details).

As for (1.), this used to be quite difficult and tricky, but now it's been essentially resolved:

**Boost StackTrace**: [Code](https://github.com/boostorg/stacktrace) | [Documentation](http://boostorg.github.io/stacktrace/index.html)

It will do the best possible to get as much stack trace info as is possible. A simple example of use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

// ... somewhere inside the `bar(int)` function that is called recursively:
std::cout << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();
```

may result in the following output:

```
0# bar(int) at /path/to/source/file.cpp:70
1# bar(int) at /path/to/source/file.cpp:70
2# bar(int) at /path/to/source/file.cpp:70
3# bar(int) at /path/to/source/file.cpp:70
4# main at /path/to/main.cpp:93
5# __libc_start_main in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
6# _start
```

**Note:** StackTrace is a very recent addition to Boost (as of August 2017); you might consider getting it independently if your Boost version is not recent enough.

Comment: But in order to use it I have to modify the source code. I don't know in which place my program hangs. Where should I place this code? Everywhere?

Comment: @YotKay: You should read the documentation; and there are several options. One is to have a signal handler for segmentation violations. Another is to throw exceptions which include a stack trace, and catch them in just one (or a few) places.

Comment: I definitely should read the documentation, I admit. But I think we misunderstand each other. My program hangs somewhere, which doesn't mean it crashes. It waits on some conditional variable or something like that. I need to find out where. Your solution doesn't help me, because I don't know where to throw this exception you mentioned etc.

Comment: @YotKay: Ah well, send it a signal and have a signal handler for it using the stack trace library.

Comment: Oops... looks like I have too old boost :-/ I need 1.65 :-/