# A shell one-liner to attach GDB to a running process, print backtrace and detach

Tags: shell, gdb

I'm debugging a hang in a parallel program running on >1000 processes. I want to get the backtraces for all of those processes. Ideally, I want a one-liner that will attach to the process, get the backtrace to stdout or a file and then detach from the program

I tried `gdb -p 1234 -ex 'thread apply all bt' -ex detach` but GDB doesn't detach after printing the backtrace

Comment: This should work. How do you know it doesn't detach?

Comment: When you say "detach", do you actually want GDB to detach AND exit?  Because those are different things.  Add '-ex exit' or use the '-batch' flag to cause GDB to exit once it's done.

Comment: `gdb -p 84653 -batch -ex 'thread apply all bt' -ex detach` works, thanks!

Comment: You can also use `eu-stack` standalone binary from elfutils, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49380036/72178.

Answer (score 3):

The `pstack` command, usage `pstack pid [...]` is supposed to be able to do this. However, the version available as a Debian/Ubuntu binary package (`sudo apt install pstack`) "currently works only on Linux, only on an x86 machine running 32 bit ELF binaries (64 bit not supported)".

Another version is available in source form at `https://github.com/peadar/pstack`. I was able to build it from source and install it on my Ubuntu system. Sample usage:

```
$ sleep 123 &
[1] 1852797
$ pstack 1852797
process: /proc/1852797/mem
thread: 0x7f5f596cd740, lwp: 1852797, type: 1
#0  0x00007f5f597b578a in __clock_nanosleep()+90 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 at clock_nanosleep.c:78
#1  0x00007f5f597ba677 in __nanosleep()+22 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 at nanosleep.c:25
#2  0x00005605badf9a00 in <unknown>() in /usr/bin/sleep
#3  0x00007f5f596f9d90 in __libc_start_call_main()+127 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 at libc_start_call_main.h:58
#4  0x00007f5f596f9e40 in __libc_start_main_impl()+127 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 at libc-start.c:392
#5  0x00005605badf9bb5 in <unknown>() in /usr/bin/sleep

$
```

Comment: There is also a tool `eu-stack` from [elfutils](https://sourceware.org/elfutils/) which does basically the same as https://github.com/peadar/pstack.

Comment: The gdb package (I'm using 7.6) has a "pstack" script, which is a simple wrapper around gdb. It works on any binary that gdb can attach to (on my system, 32 bit, 64 bit), etc.

Comment: @dash-o What OS are you using, and where did your gdb package come from? Release 7.6 is from 2013, and the gdb-7.6 sources (ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.6.tar.bz2) don't contain anything called "pstack" other than some unrelated parameter names. Could this `pstack` script be a third-party add-on? The `gdb` sources are at git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git

Comment: I'm using RedHat packaged gdb  - worked with RH7, RH6 (and per SO questions - RH5 and RH4). This is a simple script, which can be found. Sometimes this is referred to as pstack-gdb. Source is posted here: https://nanxiao.me/en/use-pstack-to-track-threads-on-linux/.
The main disadvantage is performance - starting GDB on a large binary (especially with multiple SO, C++, ...) takes time. The advantage is flexibility. gdb is very powerful - I was able to modify the script to include local variables, print global variable state, etc - for my own code.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "thread apply all bt" > gdb-cmds

gdb -p 1234 -batch -x gdb-cmds
```

works

From @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3228495/andrew

`gdb -p 84653 -batch -ex 'thread apply all bt' -ex detach` also works

Answer (score 0):

The gdb distribution has a script 'pstack', which take a PID parameter, and display the stack (with backtrace) for all threads + some additional formatting, logic for old/new kernels etc.

```
pstack 1234
```

Based on comment, looks like this script is not part of the core gdb package. It exists in RH provided builds/RPM. The script (and documentation) can be found here: https://nanxiao.me/en/use-pstack-to-track-threads-on-linux/

The main disadvantage is performance - starting GDB takes time - especially for large binaries. On the positive side - gdb is solid, and the script can be customize as needed - I created modified version that print global/local variables, etc.

Comment: `pstack` is not part of the gdb distribution. It's a separate script. On Ubuntu (and presumably on Debian) you can install it with `apt-get install pstack`. And apparently it doesn't support 64-bit binaries. On my system, it can't even attach to a process running a program compiled with `gcc -m32`.

Comment: The `pstack` I installed on my Ubuntu system is an executable, not a script. It might not be the same think you're referring to. There's code in the gdb source tree that *invokes* `/usr/bin/pstack` (which seems odd).

Comment: However I was able to build https://github.com/peadar/pstack from source, and it seems to work.